# How to attach a file to an email with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, file, email, attachment

I'm trying to automate an email-sender on Excel using VBA, from an Excel file. I want to attach a file to this email, this file has link in a Excel cell.

I tried to do this:

```
.Attachments.Add ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
```

So the file in that cell could be attach to my email. But it didn't work... Maybe changing the ".Value" could help but I don't no with what.
I can't only attach the file from his folder because it's always changing, the only thing that can be used is the link from the Excel.
I'm really new to VBA, thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Ron de Bruin has done excellent work that I've used on a number of ways of doing this here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section1.htm

Comment: You are trying to attach a `Cell.Value` try referencing the link's path on that cell instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim app, email As Object
Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set email = app.createitem(0)

With email
    .to = "foo@blahblah.com"
    .cc = ""
    .Attachments.Add Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
    .display
End With
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? You posted the same code.

Comment: Answer works provides additional code that may solve problem, can use with either ActiveCell or Cells. Problem may also be incorrect cell reference - try `Debug.Print Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value` to view cell value in immediate window, need to have FULL file path.